# Read/filter column and remove all the data with future date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter a column named "Vessel Estimated Time of Arrival" and delete all data with a future date.

For example, today's date 11/13/2020. Check and delete all data with a future date and retain all data before 11-13-2020 which is passed.

This macro executes without error but does not delete 2021 data.

```vb
Sub Sort_ETAPOD()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sRng As Range
    Dim fRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim tRow As Long
    Dim fCol As Long
    Dim tmDate As String
        
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
            
    Set fRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POD").Rows(1).Find(what:="Vessel Estimated Time of Arrival", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            
    fCol = fRng.Column
        
    tRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POD").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POD")
        Set sRng = .Range(.Cells(2, fCol), .Cells(tRow, fCol))
    End With
            
    'Date format MM-DD-YYYY
            
    tmDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            
    'performs a cell loop value to check for "vessel (...) departure..."
            
    For Each cel In sRng
            
        If Trim(Format(cel.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")) >= tmDate Then
            'marks any date greater than today() date with an "y"
            cel.Value = "y"
                
        Else
        End If
                
    Next cel
            
    Set sRng = Nothing
            
    With wb.Sheets("POD")
        Set sRng = .Range(.Cells(1, fCol), .Cells(tRow, fCol))
    End With
            
    'function deltR will remove any cel in found col with has "y" value, where "y" equals to cells that had date greater than DATE() (today)
    'passing arguments: range (sRng), delete anything not empty, on col#1 (sRng has only one range = columns("U:U" + tRow)
    Call deltpod(sRng, "y", 1)
        
End Sub
    
Private Sub deltpod(ByRef sRng As Range, ByVal aStr As String, ByVal f As Integer)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook '---This Relates to (Vessal Estimated time of arrival event)----
    
    'this sub procedure looks for a string (aStr) passed in (sRng) range object range, based on col number (f)
    With sRng
        .AutoFilter Field:=f, Criteria1:=aStr
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POD").AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Set sRng = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: are you comparing dates to strings?  Step through your code and see if any 'y's are being populated.  My guess is you've got your data types mixed up and you're trying to compare a String type with a Date type and they're two different things.

Comment: not getting your point.

Comment: you have Dim tmDate As String, which creates a text string of the date.  This is something that is completely different than what you have in your worksheet (which is a numerical representation of the date formatted to look like a date).   See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163982/excel-vba-compare-date-in-cell-to-current-date

Comment: I'd use the auto-filter myself, but for your method, I suggest not using strings but rather comparing the underlying values.  Eg change your comparison line to `If Int(cel.Value2) >= CDbl(Date) then ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution to do what you're after.  It should be used as a template and you'll need to ensure you properly set the range and do some error checking to make sure it doesn't fall over.  It should delete all of the rows that are after today's date.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range

Dim todayDate As Date

todayDate = Date

Set rng = Sheet1.UsedRange

rng.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
        ">" & todayDate, Operator:=xlAnd
        
rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any problems and I'll try and help sort it out.  Good luck!

Fair enough...I assumed you'd modify the code based on what you've already done.  Either way, here is a method that allows you to define the column header and use that rather than it being hard coded in:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim todayDate As Date

todayDate = Date

Set rng = Sheet1.UsedRange
colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("test", rng.Rows(1), 0)

rng.AutoFilter Field:=colNum, Criteria1:= _
        ">" & todayDate, Operator:=xlAnd
        
rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Keep in mind, this assumes you're using Sheet1 and your headers are the 1st row of the used range.  There are more reliable ways to set the range used, but I'll leave that change up to your discretion.  Also, don't forget to put some error checking in around the column header search (test it out if the column header isn't there) as well as some error handling around the deleting (what happens if there are no future dates).  It is usually not safe to assume that the header is always present or there are always dates in the future.

Good luck!

Comment: it works but the I want based on column name since data/column varies every time and "Field:=19" i.e. column S is constant in code which I don't want. I want to search with the column name and then delete all the future events.

Comment: Thanks this has helped me shorten my codes thanks @sous2817

Comment: @Jazz glad to help out!  If you get a minute to accept and / or 'upvote' the answer, that will help other people who have a similar problem.  Either way, good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: extremely sorry for that I missed I have accepted the answer now